# Wordpress: Object instance defined in functions.php shows NULL in footer.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm setting an instance of an object in `functions.php`, like this:

```
$foo = new Foo;
```

When I dump it out in `index.php`, it returns the instance. However, in `footer.php` this:

```
var_dump($foo)
```

returns `NULL`.

This all inside a Wordpress-theme. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in footer.php is in a different scope.  You can try making it a global with:

```
global $foo;
$foo = new foo;
```

in your functions.php file and then at the top of your footer.php file add:

```
global $foo;
```

Your var_dump should then return the object.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Didn't think of this possibility, as I thought the stuff from `functions.php` are meant to be publicly available through the theme files. Works, thanks!